# Access Lightning Component in Visualforce Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[image: Code Screenshot]

I am trying to use Lightning component in VF page, but I encounter the following error:

> Something has gone wrong. No component definiton for LightPOC in the client registry - add  to c:LightPOCApp.. Please try again.

I am trying this in my personal dev sandbox for POC on Lightning.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a syntax issue with how you are referencing component

```
<script>
     $Lightning.use("c:LightPOCApp", function() {
                    $Lightning.createComponent("c:LightPOC", {},
                     "leaderboard",
                        function(cmp) {
                         // do some stuff
                        });

                });
   </script>
```

The C namespace is needed to reference component

Comment: please upvote the answer and mark as answered to help community.Thanks!